# rule based file parsing

Tags: java, ruby, awk

I need to parse a file line by line on given rules.

Here is a requirement.

file can have multiple lines with different data..

```
01200344545143554145556524341232131
1120034454514355414555652434123213101200344545143554145556524341232131
2120034454514
```

and rules can be like this.

- if byte[0,1] == "0" then extract this line to /tmp/record0.dat
- if byte[0,1] == "1" then extract this line to /tmp/record1.dat
- if byte[0,1] == "2" then extract this line to /tmp/record2.dat

I am looking for any language which can do this in a fast manner with a very long file size like >2 GB.

Appreciate all the help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would do it in code. I don't have all your rules but I see a pattern that would make it trivial.

Comment: If all your rules are like that I think that you should focus on I/O efficiency.

Comment: Is your file binary or does it contain plain text data?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear in your list of tags, but I'd use:

```
sed -n -e '/^0/w /tmp/record0.dat' \
       -e '/^1/w /tmp/record1.dat' \
       -e '/^2/w /tmp/record2.dat' "$@"
```

You can also do it in the other languages, but for conciseness and probable correctness, in this case, `sed` is hard to beat.

Answer (score 2):

This will work regardless of the value of the first character so it scales without having to add more rules:

```
awk '{c=substr($0,0,1); print $0 > "/tmp/record" c ".dat"}' inputfile.dat
```

Comment: +1 ... Does '{print > "/tmp/record" substr($0,0,1) ".dat"}' work?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vFS= 'NF{print $0>"/tmp/record"$1".dat"}' file
```